# Using spacebar in desktop application

Tags: java, swing, keyevent

I write desktop application using Swing. I have `JFrame` and many `JButton` and `JTextField` inside frame.

Using `KeyEventDispatcher` I catch spacebar press event `Keyevent.VK_SPACE` and click in `cancelButton`

```
new KeyEventDispatcher(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
    @Override
    public void performAction(KeyEvent event) {
        cancelButton.doClick();
        cancelButton.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

It works, but on `cancelButton` other event change his state to `cancelButton.setEnabled(false)` and when I press spacebar after disable this `cancelButton` then other button in the same frame is clicked. I think this is option of system but maybe can I blocked this ? I care about this that the pressing spacebar do one thing which is declared in `KeyEventDispatcher`.

I think about change this spacebar to other letter from keyboard but I want to know that I can solved this problem using spacebar.

Any idea how to resolve this problem?

**EDIT**
I try with `CTRL` key but at every press this keys other button is highlighted like pressing `TAB`. The same action is with `C` key also when set at `JTextField` it changes value of this field.

**SOLVED**

I solved it by adding `event.consume()` and remove `cancelButton.requestFocus()`

```
new KeyEventDispatcher(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
    @Override
    public void performAction(KeyEvent event) {
        event.consume();
        cancelButton.doClick();
    }
}
```

Comment: JFrame, JButton, KeyEventDispatcher are all Swing not SWT.

Comment: You are right, my mistake :)